# Using Arrow Keys to Move TextBox on MouseOver Event?

Tags: vb.net

I am working with VB 2015, and in my form I have 5 TextBox.  I would like to reposition these TextBox using the arrowkeys when I mouseOver a label.  For example if the user mousesOver a "H" label, he can then use just the Left or Right arrow keys, if they mouseOver a "L" label, they can use the up or down arrow keys.

I can easily find a mouseOver event;

```
Private Sub lblDateH_MouseEnter(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles lblDateH.MouseEnter
    MessageBox.Show("You Moused Over")
End Sub
```

And I can find arrow keys;

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean
    'detect up arrow key
    If keyData = Keys.Up Then
        MessageBox.Show("You pressed Up arrow key")
        Return True
    End If
    'detect down arrow key
    If keyData = Keys.Down Then
        MessageBox.Show("You pressed Down arrow key")
        Return True
    End If
    'detect left arrow key
    If keyData = Keys.Left Then
        MessageBox.Show("You pressed Left arrow key")
        Return True
    End If
    'detect right arrow key
    If keyData = Keys.Right Then
        MessageBox.Show("You pressed Right arrow key")
        Return True
    End If
    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```

So how can implement both?

I will then be using the ApplicationSettingsBase to store these settings on form close.

Comment: You need two vars to store data outside, one you set to true when you mouseover enter, false when leave, to the other you assign which textbox is it.
Then on they keypress you check if that first var is true and move the textbox.

Comment: Good point, I need to ensure the mouseLeave event is in place, or put a "save" call on the event.  Or can I call a "save" on mouseLeave?  Time to do some thinking...

Comment: So...  Why does this not work?  Pressing the KeyUp button is suppose to move the Location.Y from it's present location - 1;

If keyData = Keys.Up Then
            While keyData
                DateBox.Location.Y = DateBox.Location.Y - 1
                'MessageBox.Show("You pressed Up arrow key")
            End While
            Return True
        End If

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it, this works;

```
If keyData = Keys.Up Then
    DateBox.Location = New Point(DateBox.Location.X, DateBox.Location.Y - 1)
    'MessageBox.Show("You pressed Up arrow key")
    Return True
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Full working sub, this captures the focused controls name and passes it to the sub, it then uses the keys to relocate the textBox's.  Settings.Settings then stores the new values;

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean
    'Sub detects which arrow key is pressed
    Dim strControlName As String
    ' Get the name of the control
    strControlName = Me.ActiveControl.Name
    Dim aControl = Me.Controls.Item(strControlName)
    If strControlName <> "PrintButton" Then
        If keyData = Keys.Up Then
            aControl.Location = New Point(aControl.Location.X, aControl.Location.Y - 1)
            Return True
        End If
        'detect down arrow ke
        If keyData = Keys.Down Then
            aControl.Location = New Point(aControl.Location.X, aControl.Location.Y + 1)
            Return True
        End If
        'detect left arrow key
        If keyData = Keys.Left Then
            aControl.Location = New Point(aControl.Location.X - 1, aControl.Location.Y)
            Return True
        End If
        'detect right arrow key
        If keyData = Keys.Right Then
            aControl.Location = New Point(aControl.Location.X + 1, aControl.Location.Y)
            Return True
        End If
    End If

    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```